# Find rows that satisfy two conditions and are unique

Tags: mysql, union

Hello I have the following tables:

```
Keyword
--------------------
| id   | Value     |
--------------------
| 1    | test1     |
| 2    | test2     |
|------------------|

URL
---------------------------
| id   | URL               |
---------------------------|
| 1    | www.something.com |
|--------------------------|

Keywords_URL
---------------------------
| Keywordid   | URLid     |
---------------------------
| 1           | 1         |
| 2           | 1         |
|-------------------------|
```

So the idea is that I have many URLs linked with a keyword, a URL can have more than 1 keywords, and many URLs can have the same Keywords.

So the URL table describes the information about a specific URL, the Keywords table describes the information about the keywords and the other Keywords_URL table links the two tables.

I am looking for a query, such that will return all the URLs that has as conditions two keywords.

For instance, I would like to know, the URLs that have both "test1" **and** "test2" keywords. So the results should be all the URLs that have both keywords associated with it.

Furthermore, I want my results to be "Distinct" so no duplicate rows.

I am surprised that `MySQL` doesn't support the `INTERSECT` clause and now I am looking for a way to solve that.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
(SELECT kewyord.Value, URL.id id, FROM Keywords_URL JOIN Keyword ON Keywords_URL.Keywordid = Keyword.id JOIN URL ON Keywords_URL.URLid = URL.id WHERE Keywords.Value = "test1")
UNION DISTINCT
(SELECT kewyord.Value, URL.id id, FROM Keywords_URL JOIN Keyword ON Keywords_URL.Keywordid = Keyword.id JOIN URL ON Keywords_URL.URLid = URL.id WHERE Keywords.Value = "test2")
ORDER BY id;
```

The problem is that I do get duplicates rows, but also I am getting URLs that have one of the two keywords (i.e not all the rows satisfy that they have to have both keywords associated)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT id, URL
FROM URL
WHERE id IN (SELECT ku.URLid 
             FROM Keywords_URL AS ku 
             INNER JOIN Keyword AS k ON ku.Keywordid = k.id
             WHERE k.value IN ('test1', 'test2')
             GROUP BY ku.URLid
             HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT k.id) = 2)
```

The sub-query, used in the `WHERE` clause, selects all `URLid` having *both* `'test1', 'test2'` as their associated keywords. These values are then used by the `IN` operator to select all rows of `URL` with these `URLid`s.

Comment: Hey, thanks let me run that and I will be back to you.

Comment: That is awesome and it works perfectly fine ! Thank you so much ! The = 2 at the end of the query is used to identify that I am looking for 2 keywords or will restrict the results to be just 2?

Comment: `WHERE k.value IN ('test1', 'test2')` *guarantees* that all urls returned are associated with either `'test1'`, `'test2'` or both. The `=2` filters out those associated with *just one* of the two keywords.